# How to stop jenkins build on all nodes after the first error

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a run-of-the-mill Jenkins install using multibranch/pipeline/Jenkinsfile stuff.

The project I'm building is a C/C++ project, which must be compiled on many operating systems and architectures. For this, I have a bunch of nodes (a.k.a. agents or slaves) registered to jenkins, each doing a build of that said project, for that particular combination of operating system and architecture.

Many of those builds are executed in parallel, which is common sense. My problem is now this: I would like to stop *all* in-progress sub-builds on all nodes when an error occurs anywhere in that overall multiplatform build. For example, lets assume I'm building the code for 3 things:

1. macos
2. Linux aarch64
3. windows 10

If macos fails, I would like to automatically cancel linux and windows, even if *in-progress*, because I know for a fact that the overall build will fail: I will not be able to make a release out of those with some missing parts.

Currently, if macos fails, linux and windows are happily continuing the builds, wasting the slots for other queued jobs, electricity and time.

Any hints are appreciated!

**Update 1:**
The poor's man solution to this is to serialize the sub-builds, in a long stage-after-stage way. But that will take very long time to complete the build. So that is not an option for me

**Update 2:**
more tangible explanation:

```
stages {
    stage('Checkout') {
        ...
    }
    stage('Build') {
        parallel {
            stage ('linux') {
                ...
            }
            stage ('windows') {
                ...
            }
            stage ('mac') {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
    stage('Archive and release') {
        ...
    }
}
```

If any of mac, windows or linux builds fails, I would like the rest to be aborted immediately as well, not wait for completion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer. The trick is to add this in the pipeline configuration.

```
  pipeline {
    options {
      parallelsAlwaysFailFast()
    }
    ...
  }
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure OP is saying that this IS the answer. It's not an edit to the post.